# Set Variable Value Using Importrange Without Changing a Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

'''

```
var app = SpreadsheetApp;
var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var actsht = ss.getActiveSheet();

var hsv = app.getActive().getRange().getValue('=IMPORTRANGE("SHEET URL HERE", "sheet1!B2")')
```

'''

Aside from the "SHEET URL HERE" - which I hid to keep my actual doc private - the code above is a snippet of my attempt to assign a variable value based on the value of a cell in a different spreadsheet.

I get an error, presumably because '.getRange()' does not reference a cell, but that is because whenever I do that, it actually updates the cell in the destination spreadsheet which this script is attached to.

Is there a way to grab a value of a cell in a different spreadsheet other than IMPORTRANGE and assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

```
function grabacellinadifferentspreadsheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const oss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid');
  const oval = oss.getRange('Sheet1!B2').getValue();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const rg = sh.getRange('A1');
  rg.setValue(oval);
}
```

Comment: So "openById" is superior to "IMPORTRANGE"?

Comment: openById is the way we can access other spreadsheets on the server from a script.  It's neither  superior nor inferior it's a method for opening a spreadsheet.

Comment: I see. How can I set the value of 'A1' to a variable like I am trying to do with my code snippet above? Your code's final line 'rg.setValues(oval);' will set the value of a cell to the pulled value. I need to store that as a variable in the script to be used for a if, else in a for loop rather immediately set the value in a cell on the target spreadsheet.

Comment: For the final line in your code, can I simply write:

Comment: I am getting an error when I try to assign the value of the imported cell as shown: https://i.imgur.com/2JiFTWI.png

Comment: I left something out.

Comment: [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) doesn't require an argument as shown in the answer provided by @Cooper. See the link provided to learn more about spreadsheet service functions and objects.

Comment: @Ron M where does getValue() have and argument?

Comment: In the image shared by @Graham Palermo, OP used `const oval = oss.getRange('Sheet1!B2'); var hsv = oval.getValue("B2")` which causes an error. It should be `var hsv = oval.getValue()`

Comment: Well we all make mistakes.

Comment: Very nice, thank you @RonM. Now, the only problem I have - and it seems to be because I am using the openById(), is that people I share the sheet with cannot use the button I created : (. Even with full access, editing rights, it gives some error due to permissions.